# Specifying system properties or command line arguments when starting a daemon created using appassembler maven plugin

Tags: service, wrapper, appassembler

we would like to use appassembler-maven-plugin to generate daemon scripts for our apps, we want to avoid having multiple configuratoins and generated scripts for the different environments, e.g. test, prod, etc., and would like to be able to set a jvm system property or add an extra command line argument when starting. I have been looking into this for a while ow and can't seem to find a solution.
If anybody has any ideas or suggestions they would be greatly appreciated,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extraJvmArguments to put such things as a system property. See the [examples on the documentation page.](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-daemon-jvmsettings.html)

Comment: How would you specify different property values for each environment (e.g. one URL for dev and a different URL for prod)? If these values are specified in the maven configuration, they will be the same for all environments.

Comment: I wouldn't specify properties i would do it an other way like described [here](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2011/07/29/maven-configuration-for-multipe-environments) and [here](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/08/24/iterator-maven-plugin-0-2).